# Company branding Azure AD with Custom CSS

Tags: css, azure, azure-active-directory

I am applying `custom.css` to my sign in pages after reading [Configure your company branding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/how-to-customize-branding)

I have noticed a few `css` selectors are being filtered out. Is it true we can only apply the selectors, as found in this `css` [template](https://download.microsoft.com/download/7/2/7/727f287a-125d-4368-a673-a785907ac5ab/custom-styles-template-013023.css)?

For example, I cannot hide the secondary button, but only show it on certain screens with this css, as the following example `css` is filtered out of the page:

```
.ext-sign-in-box .ext-button.ext-secondary {
    display: none;
}

/* Only show secondary "No" button on Stay signed in? screen */
.ext-sign-in-box .ext-button.ext-secondary[value="No"] {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Lastly, I also noticed the custom css is injected into the page multiple times, is this a bug?

[image]